# Tracking user's private link on google analytics: will it be a security issue for GDPR?

Tags: user-tracking, gdpr

Our web portal track page access with google analytics.
The access link will be then tracked and exposed in google analytics reports.

As the portal include personally identifiable information (PII), will it be compliant with GDPR or it will be a serious security issue?

PS. considering uncertainty surrounding GDPR compliance, I'd like at least to know how people in similar situation are moving...

Comment: So the url contains something that can be used to identify the user that views it? Yes, this is a problem, because GA terms. Depending on other things, GDRP might be ok with it, but Google is not.

Comment: @user155462 well, the login link (eg app.com/xxxprivatlinkxxx ) to a page containing  personal data, will appear in GA. The link allows to enter the page, without further authentication. Am I doing something totally unacceptable? This link must also be sent via email